# SQL Group by not working when in use, with out it SQL works fine

Tags: mysql, sql

When I use the below SQL query it works and data shows perfectly fine, but I would like to group it by the main headdings

The image shows the working code which is below

[image: Image of working SQL data]

```
SELECT * 
FROM vtm5eDisciplines d 
LEFT JOIN vtm5eDisciplinePowers p ON d.ID = p.disciplineID 
WHERE d.vampID = $vampID 
ORDER BY d.discipline, p.powerRank, p.power
```

but when I go to add a Group by feature I get nothing (below is the inclusion of the group by)

Heres the code of the Group by included, though it doesnt show much image also

[image: Image of no SQL data when Group by is in use]

```
SELECT * 
FROM vtm5eDisciplines d 
LEFT JOIN vtm5eDisciplinePowers p ON d.ID = p.disciplineID 
WHERE d.vampID = $vampID 
GROUP BY d.ID 
ORDER BY d.discipline, p.powerRank, p.power
```

Any ideas why it will work with out the Group by but shows no error codes but just no data when including the group by??

Comment: Please provide sample data, current and desired results, as tabular text. `group by` probably does not work exactly as you think it does (typically, `select * ... group by ...` is not a sensible expression).

Comment: Your group by it is wrongly formed. You need to specify the columnscto select & the ones to use in an aggregate function.

Comment: Hey @GMB Im hoping to have a table something like (heading 1) a the top IE Dominate and then powers below, then below that the next heading for the next Discipline IE Presence

Comment: Hey @nacho ahh so if I actually specify the column name and not use the asterisk * you think it might work, Ill give it a go.

Comment: Hey @nacho I gave it a try, this is the new SQL data `SELECT d.ID, d.discipline, d.disciplineDesc, d.disciplineRank, p.power, p.powerRank, p.description, p.rouse, p.dicepool1, p.dicepool2, p.contest1, p.contest2, p.duration FROM vtm5eDisciplines d LEFT JOIN vtm5eDisciplinePowers p ON d.ID = p.disciplineID WHERE d.vampID = $vampID GROUP BY d.ID ORDER BY d.discipline, p.powerRank, p.power` but it still results in no information, If I remove the Group by it works as it use to.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Ahh @ChrisStrickland ok so if I understand it correctly, I can't group by text to show sub-text where each shares the common heading? Group by only works for Counts, Min, Max, and Sums for example where it shows a math sum value next to a heading. 

Thanks for the help, I guess back to the old drawing board :D I'm self-taught/learning so will try to find another way.

Comment: There are some other aggregate functions, but that was generally what I was saying.  But what are you trying to do.  I mean "grouping by the heading" is a little vague.  What do you expect to happen if duration or disciplineRank have more than one value in the grouped set?

Comment: Hey @ChrisStrickland, Sorry I apologise for the Vagueness in explaining I have 2 SQL Tables 1 table holds the name of the Discipline these are the main headings, and the 2nd table holds the powers (plus extra columns). There are many powers that can be linked to 1 Discipline. Ideally, I would like to have the Discipline heading with many powers below and then the new Discipline heading with those linked powers below it in an HTML table. I have a PHP If statement checking if there are Null values and preventing my echo's outputting blank data. it displays correctly as in the original images.

Comment: Ok, two things: when asking a SQL question, you should include the data, and also the data necessary to model your database.  Read these two links:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

and they will give you an idea of how to ask better.  If you do, you'll get more people to help you because it will be easier for them.

That said, what you've got isn't a SQL problem, it's a php problem. I'll put together an answer with some tips.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; this is a scripting problem, not a SQL problem.

---

**This section is about SQL aggregation.  The next section addresses the display:**

You don't group like that.  `GROUP BY` is for using aggregate functions (`MAX`, `MIN`, `AVG`, [etc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)) to get things like the maximum or average value of the set of values that are associated with a field or group of fields.  For instance:

```
SELECT field1, MIN(field_x), MIN(field_y)
FROM table
GROUP BY field1
```

will get you the minimum values for field_x and field_y for each value of field1 that exists in the database.

```
SELECT field1, field2, MIN(field_x), MIN(field_y)
FROM table
GROUP BY field1, field2
```

will get you the minimum values for field_x and field_y for each combination of field1 and field2 that exists in the database.

It seems like this isn't what you are trying to do, though.  You just want to display the data that you do have in a certain format, and that brings us to the php part of the answer.

---

**This section is about displaying the data:**

I'm not going to do a complete solution here, and I couldn't anyway because I don't know enough about your data, but I will go over one possible way to approach the display of a data set in php (btw, you should always include your versions when you ask your question, either in the tags or in the question).

Let's say this is your data:

```
|=============================================|
|Discipline  |  power               |  rank   |
|=============================================|
|Dominate    |  Cloud Memory        |  1      |
|Dominate    |  Mesmerise           |  2      |
|Dominate    |  The Forgetful Mind  |  3      |
|Presence    |  Awe                 |  1      |
|Presence    |  Daunt               |  1      |
|=============================================|
```

and you have it in an array already, which you generated something like this, iterating over the result set from mysqli (assuming you're using mysqli, which I also don't know) and pushing each row into the $data buffer array:

```
$data = [];
$results = $db->query($query);
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) { $data[] = $row(); }
$results->close();
```

What you will want to do is generate the HTML for your display dynamically from that, iterating over the buffer array and using a variable to compare the previous value of the grouping field (assuming Discipline) to the current value.  When the value changes, you dump a new header:

```
echo "<div>";

$previous = '';

foreach($data as $d) {
  
  $current = $d['Discipline'];

  if($current !== $previous) { echo "<h1>{$current}</h1>"; }

  $previous = $current;
    
  echo "<div>{$d['power']}</div><div>{$d['rank']}</div>";
  
}

echo "</div>";
```

First, this sample code starts and ends by `echo`ing the opening and closing of the outer `<div>` element.  I haven't worried about styling and layout, and this is going to generate the simplest possible html.

Initialize the `$previous` variable.  Inside each loop, you'll get the current discipline and compare it to the previous value, and if they don't match, you `echo` out a new header element containing the new discipline.  After that, set `$previous` equal to `$current` in anticipation of the next loop.

Finally (and no matter what the outcome of the comparison is), you `echo` the power and rank.  And that is just about it.  Your use case may be a little more complex, but this is the basic idea.

Let me know if this addressed your problem and was helpful, or if you have any questions.

---

For future reference (and I mentioned this in my comments), you need to include a little more information when asking questions, especially SQL questions, to make it easier for people to help you.  You'll get more answers and better quality if you do.  Here are a couple of links:

[Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

In addition, you should include your SQL engine and version, as well as the version of any other languages that you're using, in this case the PHP version.  Since I don't have that information, or even sample data, this answer is very generalized, and I kept it as simple as I could.